# How to make irb output the same on Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm have irb 1.4.1 (2021-12-25) on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. On Windows, When I type in irb `1+2`, on Windows I get `# => 3`, but on Ubuntu I get `=> 3`.

For me this is not a trivial matter, because I generate hundreds of examples for ruby-lang.org, using irb on both systems;  I need the output to be the same, so that the examples are consistent.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found irb conf.return format, which is different on the two systems.  To  set in irb, `conf.return_format = "# => %s\n"`.

Comment: I don't think that the difference depends on the **operating system**, as you suspected in your question, but on the actual Ruby built you have installed. That is, different Ruby implementations on Windows may behave differently in this respect. Also, different MRI Ruby versions may ship with differently configured `irb`.  Did you check the Ruby version on both of your platforms? For instance, I run on Windows the Cygwin build of Ruby 2.6.4, and this comes with an irb configuration which looks like your prompt on Ubuntu.